# is it possible to hide the png image but keep the drop shadow by css?

Tags: html, css

I have a png photo. "Filter: drop-shadow" worked well with my png photo. However, I want to hide my png photo and keep the shadow.

I tried to set the value of translate and drop-shadow x-axis to achieve. The below CSS code worked.

Also, I think it is possible to achieve it by using photoshop.  However, is it possible to hide the png image by CSS directly?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --distance: 100vw;
}

.photo {
  width: 100%;
  filter: drop-shadow(var(--distance) 10px 5px #ff0000);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="nba.png" alt="..." class="photo">
</div>
```

Comment: I think the only option is to use drop-shadow on the `div` container and set the `opacity` of the `img` to `0`

Comment: Please add an image to the snippet I made you. there are free pics on the web or use placeholder.com or similar

Comment: Please add a png image with some transparent areas/parts. I wonder if it would be possible to have the css shadow respect the transparent areas. I assume it will treat the image as a block element and just drop the shadow around its rectangular form.

Answer (score 0):

As user @Behrouz mentioned. Just have the img inside a div with a drop shadow. Here is a snippet below. You can see the drop shadow stays even if there is no image. Just edit the box-shadow property to your liking.

```css
.photo-shadow { 
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-shadow">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" />
</div>

<div class="photo-shadow">

</div>
```

Comment: I assume the OP likes to keep a shadow around the (curved; non-linear) edges of its png (with transparent area's). Then this solution won't work because the div is rectangular and will not follow the png's paths.

Comment: Ah that is fair. I have no idea what the image looks like all I see is the red dropshadow. But You are correct in that.

Comment: As I am using character png, the shadow is not only a box-shadow. BTW, thank you. I think using photoshop is the best method.